# MongoDB bulk operator, insert if not exists

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB bulk operation to insert documents.

What I'd like to do is insert, only if no document is found - I don't want to update if it is found (i.e., upsert).

Any ideas how to do this?

However, even in this case:

```
var obj = {
 item: 'test'
}

bulk.find({ item: {$ne : obj.item}}).upsert().updateOne(obj);
bulk.execute();
```

This doesn't seem to actually insert anything if not found.

EDIT:

I wanted to update this to clarify a bit more.

There are two operations I'm trying to perform, using bulk api, one is to update and one is to insert.

The document looks like this:

```
{
  item: 'test',
  categories: [{
     name: 'one',
     attr: 'two'
  }]
}
```

What I'd like to do is if the item value is not found, then insert the obj.  However, if it is found, then if `categories.name` is not found, `$push` the category object to the `categories` array.  If the document is found and the category exists, do nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you'd want is to maintain the same update operation but change the query. From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert):

> `Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().update(<update>);`
>   `Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().updateOne(<update>);`
>   `Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().replaceOne(<replacement>);`

With the upsert option set to true, if no matching documents exist for the **[`Bulk.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert)** condition, then the update or the replacement operation performs an insert. If a matching document does exist, then the update or replacement operation performs the specified update or replacement.

Change the query to look for documents that satisfy the condition:

```
var obj = { item: 'test' };

bulk.find(obj).upsert().updateOne({ $setOnInsert: obj });
bulk.execute();
```

In the above, if the a matching document does exist, then the update with **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)** does nothing as the update operation does not result in an insert, having found a document that matches the query.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've updated my question to clarify a bit more.  I've tried to do what you're saying, but I'm not exactly getting there.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why ON EARTH is there an `.upsert()`? Sometimes I wonder how developers managed to defy common sense. Intuitively, was it not supposed to be, `.updateOne({ $setOnInsert: obj }, { upsert: true })`? Everything falls in line, except there's always one deviating thing to make a dev's life horrible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})
```

Example from [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes):

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   {
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: 1
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```