# Finding list of users and iterating over in Node/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Below in my code I am getting a list of users based on department. Than using that list I am using for loop to check if that user location is in the Loc table or not.

```
user.find({dept: 'main'}, {}, (err, users)=>{
  for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
   var query={userid: users[i].userid};
    Loc.findOneAndUpdate({query, {$set: {locuser: user[i].locuser}}, {new: true, upsert: false}, (err, results)=>{
    if(err) {  console.log(err)
    console.log("success")
  })
  }
})
```

When I run this code it inserts last id repeatedly. Meaning if there were 4 users found it will insert 4 locations for the same one user who was last in the list while it should enter all 4 users.
Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform update operation using mongodb [bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) update

```
var bulk = Loc.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
user.find({dept: 'main'}, {}, (err, users)=>{
  users.forEach( function (userObj){
    bulk.find({userid: userObj.userid}).update(update);
  })     
})
bulk.execute(callback)
```

For more detail [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783575/mongoose-bulk-update-operation)

Comment: Does update also creates new record if it doesnt exist? My goal is to update if it exists if not create new one

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799112/mongodb-bulk-operator-insert-if-not-exists